# Question reg. authenticating wcf operations

Tags: wcf

I've a WCF service in which most of the operations require username and password to be passed except some. I'm planning to create a custom behavior but confused which one to go either service behavior or operation behavior?

Vijaya Anand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at using [Custom Username Password Validator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702565.aspx) in WCF. This may solve your problem.

Look at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/03/14/wcf-extensibility.aspx to understand the extensibility points in WCF which include Service and Operation Behaviour.